# JSReport Generation in Web api

Tags: jsreport

I have the two different web api project.

one will acting as a "API" and one will acting as a "Front end using angularjs".

how can i implement the jsreport in my project?

is it possible to implement the jsreport in web api front end using angularjs by fetching the data from another api project?

please help me out to reach the proper solution.

because i have seen jsreport is perfect to generate the front end report in the pdf format.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the JsReport .NET integration available via NuGet, and use the service method your web API uses to generate the data for a request to JsReport from the back-end.  The [documentation](http://jsreport.net/learn/net-client) is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use Web API as the data provider for your report and generate the report. You can get the article about getting started with Jsreport from [here](https://letsdebug.wordpress.com/2016/04/18/reporting-using-jsreport/).

Answer (score -1):

here is how you can Generation JSReport  in your angular app using api

```js
app.controller('mainCtrl' , function($scope, $http){
  $scope.yourData = {
  //your data goes here
  }
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "http://localhost:3001/api/report",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers":{
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      },
      "processData": false,
      "data": {"template": { "shortid" : "short-id-of-your-template", "recipe": 'html'},"data": yourData
      }
      }
    }
    $http(settings).then(function(responce){     
              $scope.htmlresponce = responce.data
              console.log(responce.data)//your html of jsreport will go here
    })
  }

})
```

replace "short-id-of-your-template" with your template shortId